# How to add a new column of numbers when performing least square analysis?

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I am trying to perform least square analysis on some values and wanted to know how I can create a new column of squared numbers. For example, I currently have this:

```
1 2
1 4
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
```

I want to make add a new column after the second column and have it automatically square. It is a huge dataset- over 500 values so doing it manually is hard.
This is what I want to do.

```
1 2 4
1 4 16
1 3 9
1 4 16
1 5 25
1 6 36
```

Comment: `A=[1 2;1 4; 1 3; 1 4;1 5;1 6];
B=[4 16 9 16 25 36]';
A=[A B]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = [1 2; 1 4; 1 3; 1 4; 1 5; 1 6];
B = [A A(:,2).^2]
```